# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed while using dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper, sqldatareader

While retrieving the records from table using dapper framework I am getting the below error

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

and below is my code

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM LMS_QuestionCategory";
                var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

                using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
                {
                    var reader = dbConnection.ExecuteReader(sql);

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dict[reader.GetName(i)] = reader.GetInt32(i);
                        }

                        rows.Add(dict);
                    }
                }
```

Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must open the connection:

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
{
   dbConnection.Open() //<--open the connection
   var reader = dbConnection.ExecuteReader(sql);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my very specific case, I was using a CommandDefinition for the select and it was throwing the referenced error:

```
CommandDefinition queryDefinition = _queryBuilder.UpdateQuery(_dbConn, _transaction, collectionName, item);

await QueryAsync<T>(CommandDefinition);
```

I changed it as follows and it worked:

```
await QueryAsync<T>("SELECT * FROM table_name",param,null,null, commandType : CommandType.Text);
```

Hope it helps to somebody